# Style Cop Auto Generated code

Tags: c#, stylecop, auto-generate

We are using style cop in VS2013 c# solution. I am running in to a specific scenario where the auto generated code files don't have the // tag as the header. These are the files I have  in the integration test project for Workflow designer files, with code - behind auto generated files, they are re-created during the build process every single time. So adding the header doesn't help.

Is there a permanent solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Do the generated files have a consistent file name?  If so, you should be able to use the StyleCop.settings file to exclude the file based on a regex. http://stylecop.codeplex.com/discussions/394180

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your Settings.StyleCop file:

```
<Parsers>
  <Parser ParserId="StyleCop.CSharp.CsParser">
    <ParserSettings>
      <CollectionProperty Name="GeneratedFileFilters">
        <Value>\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_.+\.cs$</Value>
      </CollectionProperty>
    </ParserSettings>
  </Parser>
</Parsers>
```

Comment: Remember that the contents of the <Value> element is a regular expression that is used to match the file names of your generated files.